# (un)wptexturize() -- is it possible?

Tags: characters

I have some text stored in a string `$text` that's filtered through `the_content` and therefore, [wptexturize()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize).

**wptexturize()** is a function that replaces various characters into more *prettier ones*.

Is there any way that I can **un**wptexturize() the string? Revert it back to what it was.

## What I've danced with so far

I can replace smart quotes with regular ones like this:

```
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

But that will *only* cover the smart quotes, there are a lot more characters.

Another alternative is to write a custom regex to replace all these characters back to their original ones.

Comment: Is it a possibility to run `the_content` without `wptexturize()`, extract the string you want and then parse the content again applying `wptexturize()`? Otherwise a regex seems the way to go, but it's not going to be very performant.

Comment: @LuisSanz Unfortunately no, the text in `$text` is already converted by the time I can do anything with it.

Comment: Why is it? Is it possible for you to capture the original `$text` with the [`run_wptexturize`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/run_wptexturize) filter without interrupting `wptexturize()` and get your string from it?

Comment: Does the text comes from post content? If so, you could register a `[notexturize]` shortcode, add it to [`'no_texturize_shortcodes'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/no_texturize_shortcodes/) to prevent texturize and use a shortcode callback that just return the content as is: `add_shortcode( 'notexturize', function($args, $text='') { return $text; } );`

Comment: @gmazzap This is an interesting approach (thanks!) but the content we're targeting has already gone through the wptexturize makeover and there is no way around it unfortunately. We're simply going to write our own unwptexturize() which shouldn't be difficult. We'll post it here once it's done!

Answer (score 3):

Don't think so after skimming through the `wptexturize()` code, but what about using the [`run_wptexturize`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L82) filter (untested):

```
// Turn off wptexturize
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );

// Your text handling here ...
$text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );

// Remove filter
remove_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );
```

i.e. just turn off the `wptexturize` only for your text handling?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, the text is already filtered through `the_content` at a point where I can't adjust it so this would not be possible in my scenario.

Comment: Maybe others have better ideas ;-) but I guess a code example might be helpful to better understand your setup. It sounds time consuming trying to construct a `unwptexturize()` function with preg_replace, but I think it would need to be "bijective". I'm not even sure `wptexturize()` is "injective" @ChristineCooper